# How to enable structured logging in Xcode 15 while also disabling debug logs in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode15, structured-logging

Right now my project has environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=info` enabled in the Xcode scheme (test section) to prevent debug logs during unit tests however this environment variable also disables Xcode 15's structured logging.

Is there a way to both prevent logging during unit tests *and* allow structured logging?

[image]